# hMailServer - Create a Local Blacklist Database

Tags: email, hmail-server

I just started off working with hMailServer 5.6.4 . I require a local database list storing email address in whitelist, greylist and the blacklist.

Whitelist - Email that are uninterrupted
Blacklist - Email that are automatically discarded
Greylist - Email is to be stored temporarily until a check is made

As i was looking through the database tables that were created, i did not see any "hm_blacklist" table. I did research online but did not get a clear answer if there is a blacklist or not.

Would anybody kindly advice me if hMailServer has blacklist table or not, or is it under a different name or we have to do some modification to include the table or something? Thank You.

(More on Blacklist... My intention is to store the sender's email address in the blacklist. This list would be used in future when filter email being received by the same user.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the hmailserver rules,
You can create a rule like SPAM redirection when you find a keyword in the body or header.
You can apply such a rule in an account or in all existing accounts.
Better update such feature in the admin panel and not in the database to avoid caching issues.